# How to install the email provider for apache airflow?

Tags: airflow

How do we  `pip3 install` the `email` operator for `apache-airflow` ?

`ImportError: cannot import name 'EmailOperator' from 'airflow.operators`

I would imagine it were similar to :

```
pip3 install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive==4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Email provider.
There used to be a [backport of email provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-email/) for Airflow 1.10 but then the project decided against that so `EmailOperator` was moved back to Airflow core (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/10013)).

To answer your question you get the `EmailOperator` directly from Airflow core:

```
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
```